# do I need to save a new version every time I edit app script code for a UI?

Tags: google-apps-script, publish

following the tutorial for google app script - Building user interfaces HTMLservice section

all is well with the initial simple hello world demo - one jave script file and one HTML file.

if I edit the HTML body to,say  foo bar  and the use the menu item Publish - then update - the resultant web page has not changed.

if I save a new version after that minor edit and publish the new version, then sure, the new HTML is displayed.

but surely I don't have to save a new version after every edit...

are there any clues as to why "update" (without a version change) might not work - cacheing?

with many thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Okay so answering my own question.

The Deploy as web app dialog contains a text field with the latest URL, but a small piece of text below that says

> Test web app for your latest code

latest code is a link which when pressed outputs the latest SAVE.
The URL in the text field is the latest VERSION.

Perhaps this could be part of the deploying tutorial at

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps

Problem solved!

Comment: change version flow https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions#createVersion